# Centos7でスワップイン・スワップアウトが行われた際に、システム領域でI/Oが発生する理由

Tags: linux, centos

### 前提

CentOS 7 が稼働しているサーバで swap を使用する運用が実施されることになりました。
システム領域に対して I/O を頻繁に発生させたくないと考え、 SSD を swap 領域としてサーバにマウントさせました。

---

### 発生している問題

しかし、いざスワップアウト・スワップインするとシステム領域と swap 領域の両方に対してI/Oが発生しています。

- 何が原因でこのような動作になってしまうのでしょうか？
- SSD にのみ I/O が発生する状態にするためにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか?

#### `/etc/fstab` の記述

```
 /dev/mapper/blade3--system--works-root /                        xfs     defaults        0 0
 UUID=cd5f8eba-de07-494f-b829-e57a1a124e56 /boot                 xfs     defaults        0 0
 /dev/sda1 swap                                                  swap    defaults        0 0 swap  defaults  0 0
```

#### `swapon -s`

```
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda1                               partition       488385556       13329508                             -1
```

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

- CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

Comment: 「I/Oが発生している」は具体的にどのような方法で確認されましたか？スワップ領域を使っていようと、システム領域へのI/Oがゼロになるってことは無いと思うのですが…

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます!! I/Oはもともと0ではなかったのですが、スワップアウトが始まってから明らかにI/Oの値が上昇したため「I/Oが発生している」と考えています。

Comment: 失礼しました。確認方法についてはvmstatとzabbixにて確認しています。

Comment: 既に確認済みだったり、見当違いなことを書いていたらすみません。 / `/etc/fstab`に書いただとswap領域は有効になりませんがこの点は大丈夫でしょうか。 / スワップなりI/Oを発生させるような何かプログラム(プロセス)が動いているものと思いますが、これがログファイルや一時ファイルの形でシステム領域にデータを書き込んでI/Oを発生させている、という可能性はありませんか？

Comment: swap領域に関してはswapon -sで確認するとssdがswap領域として表示されるため、swap領域は正常にマウントされていると考えています。(sdaはssdです。)

Comment: また、「 / スワップなり...ありませんか」に関してですが、
ログに関しては吐かれているのですがそれが原因だとすると
あまりにもI/Oの値が高いため、これが原因ではないと考えています。　

しかし、一時ファイルについては発想がありませんでした。
アドバイスありがとうございます!　
現在、一時ファイルやバッファキャッシュが存在していないか確認中です。

Comment: 質問からは問題点がわかりにくく回答が難しいと感じてます。I/Oが発生する事自体はふつうのことなのでどういった点が問題なのか？質問を読んだ第三者がわかるように 編集されることをおすすめします。SOでは質問の編集は推奨されておりますので一度ご検討ください。コメントを拝読すると「IOが高い」ことが問題点であると感じておられるようにも思えました。もしそうなら、そういった趣旨の内容に変更されれば、詳しい人が回答をしてくれると思いますよ。